# Which way does the gradient point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, gradient-flows

I'm extremely confused about which way the gradient points.
If given the equation $z = x^3+y^3-6xy$, I could calculate the gradient at point (1, 2, -3) by rearranging the equation to $f(x,y,z) = x^3+y^3-6xy -z = 0$, and get a gradient of (-9, 6, -1).

But i could also rearrange to $f(x,y,z) = z-x^3-y^3+6xy = 0$, and get a gradient of (9, -6, 1), which points in the opposite direction. How do I know which way the gradient is supposed to point? Is rearranging in one of these ways wrong?

Comment: Think about it in one dimension. It shows the direction (positive or negative) of increase, that is, $f(x)>0$ means increase $x$ to get larger $f$ values and vice versa. In multiple dimensions, it is the same idea, each axis has an increasing/decreasing direction.

Comment: You take gradients of functions, not of functions set equal to $0$.

Comment: The gradient of $-f$ will always be the opposite of the gradient of $f$. You didn't just rearrange $f$ you reversed it completely.

Comment: Note that you went from $z=f(x,y)$ to $g(f,z)=0$.  You're trying to relate $\nabla f$ to $\nabla g$.  Not the same thing.

Comment: Also, the gradient of $f(x,y)$ should be a 2-component vector, not one of 3 components.

Comment: @Randall I'm taking the gradient of $f(x, y, z)$, which is a 3D surface. I believe setting it to zero is similar to making a level surface, and the gradient is supposed to be normal to this surface. The answer key has the answer as (-9, 6, -1).

Comment: That's a different question.  $z=f(x,y)$ is a surface (2D) in 3-space.  A level surface takes a function $g(x,y,z)$ and sets it equal to $0$.   Then the approach is different.

Comment: @copper.hat I see what you mean. But then how is this gradient supposed to be calculated given the original equation? The equation gives a 3D surface, and the gradient is supposed to be normal to the surface. How do I know which way the gradient supposed to point?

Comment: @Randall What is the approach?

Comment: @user707586  There are typically TWO normal directions in your case.

Comment: It only makes sense to talk about gradient of a function. If you define a function $f(x,y,x) = x^3+y^3-6xy$ then the gradient is well defined.

Comment: Thanks guys! I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

The gradient of a function of 2 variables $f(x,y)$ is $(\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y)$. In your case you happen to have used $z$ as the symbol for your function so the gradient is $(\partial z/\partial x, \partial z/\partial y)$.

Now, it is another matter if you want to find *a* normal vector to some surface. The normal is parallel to the gradient vector of the level surfaces. It doesn't matter which way you re-arrange your function in to a level surface. Yes the 'gradients' (i.e. the vector of partial derivatives) point in opposite directions but this doesn't matter because they are parallel and either are suitable as a normal vector. In other words, if $\vec{n}$ is a normal vector, then so is $-\vec{n}$.

Comment: Thanks! This answer helped clarify things.